# Questions imposing constraints on answer clarity or structure

Tags: discussion, questions

I just encountered a question with the final sentence

> Provide each step clearly.

I have come across many of these kinds of "requests." Besides the fact that I consider them somewhat impolite<sup>1</sup>, I don't know whether to remove these sentences or not. They *do* provide some relevant information concerning how to structure your answer and how the OP can make the best use of it but OTOH, even this constraint shouldn't be needed, IMO.

Should we edit something like that out just like "Thanks" or "Regards"? Or should I leave it as it is, maybe add a "please" to alleviate my "displeasure"<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> I always imagine someone sitting in front of their computer having some assignment to finish and, because being too lazy to research on their own, asking a (maybe even off-topic) questions on SO. A little leading/trailing "please" would already eliminate this prejudice, I guess.

Comment: "Clearly" is clearly subjective. In such cases, you may want to remind the poster that SO is not for providing full tutorials. It's quite similar to "assignment: *xxx...* How do I start?" (where I often whimisically suggest 'open Notepad, call back when you got that far").

Comment: That sentence is useless. If he at least said *which part* we should explain more carefully because he has trouble with it, *that* might be useful. So, remove it. And no, expanding it without adding that information won't help.

Comment: It does smack of a homework question or some kind of assigned task. And a lot of laziness on the asker's part.

Comment: At the same time, I have seen many reasonably asked questions which receive a dump of fixed code with no explanation - which is hardly helpful to someone in the future without exactly the same parameters as the original asker. Those looking to actually learn need explanations as well as answers, otherwise yes, this site is just for helping with homework.

Comment: If it's an otherwise good-quality question that deserves to live on the site, I'd edit that line out, as it doesn't contribute to the lasting quality of the content on the site.   If it's a lazy "gimme teh codez" question that should probably be downvoted into deletion, I'd leave it there, as a warning to other users.  : )

Comment: One could argue that in the case of a homework-ish question, which we usually want to be downvoted and probably closed, leaving it as-is will help its true nature shine brighter, which helps reviewers more decisively press the close button.

Comment: @DanLowe While I agree we should not polish turds, some (not all) question with a comment like that could be edited into shape. If that is the case, it's origin as homework is irrelevant.

Comment: The right place to request clarification on answers is in comments on them, _after_ they're written. Edit out that noise. It's not constructive.

Comment: my favorite is *"explain each line of code, what it does and how in detail"* and then a code dump and nothing else

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It is a trigger phrase, there are many, that tells you that the OP is a student that simply copy/pasted his homework assignment.  Such constraints generally fall into a category of finding very impractical solutions to common problems.  The goal of course is not to find the best solution but to force the student to think for himself and rehearse the course material.  Only decent way the teacher can rate the work is seeing the steps described clearly.

And, I suspect, a trick that teachers use to stop the student from asking somebody else to do the work for him.  The WTF response you uttered here is expected :)

Personally, in the very rare case that I answer such a question, I dismiss the constraints and post the best solution that any programmer should use.  Which is what this site is all about.

Comment: Nice. And without remorse for the poor student that has to explain why he submitted a fifth grade answer to a first grade question.

Comment: I agree with Hans. There should be a _trigger warning_ above such questions!

Comment: @Jongware in an ideal world, the student would then read up on how exactly the solution works. And then the teacher will be impressed. I know some people in my class that did this.

Comment: That's fine too. There's nothing explicitly wrong with helping people with their homework. There's a lot wrong with outsourcing your homework to the internet. Therefore by giving a solution that is good practice, but perhaps beyond the level of the supplicant you accomplish both - either they take time to truly grok it, and understand more as a result, or they don't and they're caught out by it.

Comment: There should be a list of such 'homework tells', eg.any question with 'Consider' as the first word in the body is a dead cert for immediate down/close vote.

Comment: Add  'Please explain' to the list... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487755/what-is-the-output-of-this-code-please-explain

Comment: Hobby suggestion: answering these questions in a horribly overkill way, that will make it evident for the teacher that the student could not have done it by themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502414/order-of-arguments-in-printf

Comment: @AndrasDeak I've used my interest in Code Golfing to answer homework questions a couple of times. It's always fun.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but solution MUST be regex solution!

Comment: @MartinJames - I have seen this exact question on SO years ago. Must be from a curriculum.

Answer (score 7):

You should edit it out. Why?

1. The answers are not just there to please the OP, but to help future visitors as well. The OP's personal preferences for how the answer should be structured are therefore irrelevant (or at least not more relevant than the preferences of anybody else).
2. When it is a very vague request that essentially boils down to "please write a good answer", it conveys zero extra information. We should always try to write good answers. Pointing that out on individual questions is useless.

Comment: I read this answer as meaning "[You should] edit it out."  Then he provided two reasons in answer to "Why?"

Comment: The answers are not *just* here to please OP, but it is the primary goal. Stack Overflow is a place where *you* can get a solution for your programming problem, not where *you* can ask a question, so you get a bunch of answers that are irrelevant to you but may help future visitors. If the question cannot or will not be answered in such a way that OP is satisfied, I think it's better to close/delete the question altogether than to edit it in such a way that a future visitor may benefit from it. If needed, that future visitor will ask their own question, which then is hopefully better written.

Comment: I disagree - I think helping the supplicant is more like a beneficial side effect of collating the Stack Overflow knowledge base. You _should_ answer as if it's a general case, and thus a good question will help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: @Sobrique In turn, I disagree. A "beneficial side effect" sounds too drastic to me; it suggests that answering the OP's question is not the original intent but rather providing a resource for future visitors *exclusively*. If the OP's questions is answered, "lucky for him/her." Then, why don't we exclusively self-answer our questions? The term "secondary goal" might be better suited here as this clearly states it as a **goal**.

Comment: Because the person answering a question isn't necessarily the person asking it, and if you understand a thing, you don't tend to bother to ask questions about it. In order to have a collated knowledge base you need good answers. To get good answers you (usually) need good questions. One way to get good questions is to open it to anyone to ask, and ... well, filter out the  junk - which is exactly what Stack Overflow does. It's nice when the supplicant gets an answer that meets their needs, certainly. But votes are based on the consensus of how good/useful an answer is by _everyone else_.

Comment: @Sobrique Alright, but what about the "why is my code not working?" questions, like in shape of the famous "Floating point math broken" question? Technically, some beginner might've asked this question but after all, it evolves to be one of the highest-rated questions ever. My point is, how does a novice know if her/his question is good or not? Also, you might edit the "if you understand a thing" part. At first I thought you meant me and took it somewhat offensive. :-)

Comment: Apologies - I can't edit any more. It wasn't aimed at you, no. Merely as Einstein put it: "If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it". So to get the best answers, you need a good question and a relative expert. Self answers do count here, but honestly - experts rarely need to ask, and knowing what someone else doesn't understand is difficult. A 'good question' is one that follows the [ask] guidance - it doesn't need to be complicated, but does require a little effort for the free help. And - "Why is my code not working" has a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints are important to clarify a question when there's a reason common wisdom might not be applicable. Things like being limited to a particular version/module/OS or needing to do formal change process paperwork to install "extra stuff".

However in my opinion they're only valid if future readers might be suffering the same constraints - and even then, it is still valuable to ignore them if the *right* way is to do something different.

So with that in mind - if a constraint clarifies the context of the question, then it's valuable to keep. And if it doesn't, then it's just noise and should go. That goes double with 'homework' style questions, where the constraints are artificial and by imposing them the question becomes of limited use to future readers.

Comment: I think we need to differentiate between different kinds of constraints here. Constraints about how to solve the problem (like "using PHP on an Apache server"), and constraints on how to write the answer (like "Provide each step clearly.") I interpreted this question as being about the second kind, but not the first kind.

Comment: Agreed. As did I. The ones the clarify are good constraints to be kept. The ones that do not are noise and should go. That was what I was hoping to put forward anyway...

Comment: An answer choosing to ignore a constraint in the question is fine.  Readers can choose, when voting on the answers, whether or not the answer is useful in light of the fact that it choose to ignore the given constraints.  That doesn't make it okay to *edit them out of the question*.  If  you think that a given question wouldn't be useful then the appropriate response is *to downvote it*.  That's what votes are for.  But editing a question into a *completely different question* isn't appropriate just because you think that the new question would be more useful.